# RSASSA-PSS Signature Algorithm In Android

Tags: android, security, rsa

In Android's official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Signature), it's stated that RSASSA-PSS is amongst supported Signature algorithms.

But when I try

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("RSASSA-PSS");
```

I receive java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSASSA-PSS Signature not available. Tried both in a real device and emulator with Android version 9.0 (Api Level 28).

Does anyone know why it doesn't exist?

**Edit:** How can I use it in Android API level 8+?

Comment: RSASSA-PSS is supported for API levels  1-8, not all

Comment: Isn't there any way to use it in API level 8+? Using support libraries, etc.?

Comment: Thank you, @Rahul Patil. But removing support for particular module in later API revisions? This is the first time I see something this awkward in a big project. This means not all programs running in API 1-8 run in later API versions for some non-existent reason.